# Sub2ind with three dimension - access all of dimension

Tags: arrays, matlab

Say A is a 3x4x5 array. I am given a vector a, say of dimension 2 and b of dimension 2. If I do A(a,b,:) it will give 5 matrices of dimensions 2x2. I instead want the piecewise vectors (without writing a for loop).

So, I want the two vectors of A which are given by (a's first element and b's first element) and (a's second element and b's second element)

How do I do this without a for loop? If A were two dimensions I could do this using sub2ind. I don't know how to access the entire vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sub2ind` to find the linear index to the first element of each output vector: `ind = sub2ind(size(A),a,b)`. To get the whole vectors, you can't do `A(ind,:)`, because the `:` has to be the 3rd dimension. However, what you can do is reshape `A` to be 2D, collapsing the first two dimensions into one. We have a linear index to the vectors we want, that will correctly index the first dimension of this reshaped `A`:

```matlab
% input:
A = rand(3,4,5);
a = [2,3];
b = [1,2];

% expected:
B = [squeeze(A(a(1),b(1),:)).';squeeze(A(a(2),b(2),:)).']

% solution:
ind = sub2ind(size(A),a,b);
C = reshape(A,[],size(A,3));
C = C(ind,:)

assert(isequal(B,C))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change a and b to be 3d arrays just like A and then the sub2ind should be able to index the whole matrix. Like this:

Edit: Someone pointed out a bug. I have changed it so that a correction gets added. The problem was that ind1, which should have had the index number for each desired element of A was only indexing the first "plane" of A. The fix is that for each additional "plane" in the z direction, the total number of elements in A in the previous "planes" must be added to the index.

```
A=rand(3,4,5);
a=[2,3];
b=[1,2];
a=repmat(a,1,1,size(A,3));
b=repmat(b,1,1,size(A,3));
ind1=sub2ind(size(A),a,b);

correction=(size(A,1)*size(A,2))*(0:size(A,3)-1);
correction=permute(correction,[3 1 2]);
ind1=ind1+repmat(correction,1,2,1);
out=A(ind1)
```

Comment: In your example A is of dimension 2 not 3.

Comment: No, when I initialize it it is of dimension 2. In the next line I make it 3 dimensional using the repmat function. I realize I forgot to initialize a and b in my example so I have edited it. You should be able to run it now

Comment: Yes you are right. I missed that. I have added a correction to the code

Comment: your solution gives me an error: "Array dimensions must match for binary array op" on the second last line

Comment: Thanks avermaet. I have changed this in the answer